# Show that $a_1:= a,b_1:= b$,$a_{n+1}:=\sqrt{|a_n||b_n|} ; b_{n+1}:=\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$ generate nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let be $ 0 < a < b \; \ a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, and we define the recursive sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{R}},(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{R}} \;  a_1:= a,b_1:= b$
$$a_{n+1}:=\sqrt{|a_n||b_n|} ; b_{n+1}:=\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$$
Show that the intervals $I_n := [a_n,b_n] \ ;n \in \mathbb{N}$ generate nested intervals, an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is exisiting such that
$$x = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =  \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

My idea:

for 2 arbitrary not equal, non integer $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \ge0,x\neq y$

$0 < (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 = x - 2\sqrt{xy}+y \implies 2\sqrt{xy} < x+y \implies \sqrt{xy}<\frac{x+y}{2}$

Which means that $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{{a_n}b_{n}}< \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}, $if$ \ a_1 \neq b_1$

for $a_n = \sqrt{{a_n}{a_n}} < \sqrt{{a_n}{b_n}}< \sqrt{{b_n}{b_n}} = b_n \implies a_n < a_{n+1} < b_n$

$a_n = \frac{a_na_n}{2} < \frac{a_nb_n}{2}<\frac{b_n+b_n}{2}=b_n \implies a_n<b_{n+1}<b_n$

so the sequence is nested intervals the subsequence $a_n$ monotic increasing and $b_n$ is monotonic decreasing.

my second idea is to show that:

$a_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_{n+1} \le b_n$ and after showing it maybe using the Sandwich theorem I can show the limits for $a_n,b_n$

I think that my second idea is much better but I still don't know how could I continue it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I guess it's a typo. Should it be $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2+b_n^2}{2}}$?

Comment: thank you, I have edited the question

Comment: Why would you need to use absolute values when all the values are positive?

Comment: the absolute values are in the text of the exercise, actually I was also thinking about it, that it makes no sense

Comment: In the $b$ formula, you have index 1 on the right side? Your last inequalities are excessive (and missing some plus signs), you only need to show each inequality in the chain $a_n<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1}<b_n$.